# How to sum columns (and rows) and make a new data frame in R

Tags: r, statistics, sum, row

I have a series of measures, the data looks like this:

```
Subject    Group   QP1   QP2   QP3   QP4   QP5
1          high    yes   yes   no    yes   no
2          low     no    yes   no    no    yes
3          high    no    no    no    no    no
4          low     yes   no    yes   no    yes
5          low     yes   no    no    no    yes
```

I want to be able to:

(1) Make a new data frame that tallies each column count (how many "yes", how may "no"), but for high and low groups individually, so that I can run some stats between groups on each of the measures.
(2) Then sum the final tallies between groups (i.e. I want to know the total score for QP1 through QP5 for each group.

So my data would look like (1):

```
Group   QP1   QP2   QP3   QP4   QP5
high    2      1     3    0      4
low     3      4     2    5      1
```

And (2):

```
Group   Total QP1:QP5
high         10
low          15
```

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: how are you getting 2 and 3 for high and low under QP1

Comment: I just arbitrarily generated numbers for the example, but these numbers are pulled from questionnaires, such as "How many drinks have you had in this past week?".

Comment: Yeah, I meant using our example I am not able to figure out how you are getting 2 and 3 for high and low under QP1. if you could explain, it would be helpful to answer